# Does Selenium Support Automation of Oracle Applications Forms & Reports?

Tags: selenium, oracleapplications

Oracle Applications are Built On Java, Yet I see very less references about Automation using Selenium.
I know Oracle Application Testing Suite (built on Selenium) does support Automation. But would like to know in absence of OATS.
Any related info would be highly appreciated.

Comment: there are paid suites like `Data Loader` and `Rapid Suite`. Not sure, if you want to automate or test something!

Answer (score 0):

Only HTML based websites can be tested with Selenium. If the Oracle application exposes an HTML based front end that is accessible via a web browser then you can use Selenium to test it otherwise, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Application Testing Suite is not built on Selenium my friend. Open script tool built on Eclipse IDE

Tol and Owned and supported by Oracle itself, it supports most of Oracle Built applications.
Oracle Forms automation bets done in OATS(Oracle Applications Testing Suite)